# Show that $-\frac{2yx^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ is bounded.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

> Show that $-\frac{2yx^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ is bounded.

I'm approaching this starting with
$$ \left| \frac{2yx^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \right| = \left| \frac{2yx^3}{x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4} \right| \leq \left| \frac{2yx^3}{2x^2y^2} \right| = \left| \frac{x}{y}\right|.$$

However, this doesn't get me anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to ask, instead, how can you prove what's being asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By AM-GM,
$$ |yx^3| = 27\left|y\cdot\frac{x}{3}\cdot\frac{x}{3}\cdot\frac{x}{3}\right| \leq 27\left(\frac{|x|+|y|}{4}\right)^4 = \frac{27}{64}(|x|+|y|)^4$$
while by AM-QM:
$$ \frac{x^2+y^2}{2} \geq \left(\frac{|x|+|y|}{2}\right)^2 $$
hence:
$$\left|\frac{2yx^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\leq \frac{\frac{27}{32}}{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{27}{8}.$$
An even sharper bound (thanks to [Git Gud](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55235/git-gud)) is:
$$\left|\frac{2yx^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\leq \left|\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\right|\cdot \left|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq 1,$$
but the sharpest possible bound is given by $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8}$, as shown in the comments.

Comment: Interesting. Is this the most straightforward approach? I would not have thought of this.

Comment: @mathjacks: Honestly I don't know if it is "the most straightfoward", it is just the first one that came into my mind. We can also consider that our function just depends on the ratio between $x$ and $y$: if we take $z=x/y$, we have just to prove that $$\frac{2z^3}{(z^2+1)^2}$$ is bounded, that is also quite trivial since the numerator is a third-degree polynomial while the denominator is a non-vanishing fourth-degree polynomial.

Comment: @mathjacks: (follow-up) by considering derivatives, the min/max points of the previous function lie in $z=\pm\sqrt{3}$, so the absolute value of $f(x,y)$ is bounded by $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8}$ (this is the optimal bound).